# How do you correctly identify beta emission reactions given a description like $^{126}_{50}\text{Sn}\rightarrow^{126}_{51}\text{Sb}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

Ex. “This is an example of what type of nuclear reaction: 126/50 Sn -> 126/51 Sb”

I thought it was fusion since the atomic number increased, but it was actually beta- emission with a neutron turning into a proton and electron/e- neutrino pair.

Comment: The number of nucleons (neutrons + protons) remained the same. That is the key point that it is a beta (plus or minus) or electron capture reaction.

Comment: Seems like you should make this an answer

Comment: BTW, $\beta-$ emission emits an electron antineutrino, which conserves lepton number.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.